# Gráfico no ggplot fica vazio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando criar um gráfico de linha simples no R com o ggplot2 porem o gráfico sempre fica vazio

```
ggplot(Pasta1, aes(x = mes, y = fat))
geom_line()
```

[Imagem mostrando o código em execução
[image: Imagem mostrando o código em execução]
<sup>clique para visualizar a imagem em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfZJb.png)

[Base utilizada
[image: Base utilizada]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRaAh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Vc esqueceu o sinal de `+` para ligar `ggplot()` ao `geom_line()`.

Tente:

```
ggplot(Pasta1, aes(x = mes, y = fat))+
  geom_line()
```